# How to use NSPredicate to search for ObjectID of a relationship attribute using CoreData in Swift 5?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, nspredicate

I ran into a problem with my **CoreData database** while trying to use `NSPredicate` to **only fetch data** that **belong to a specific profile**.

```swift
let request: NSFetchRequest<Data> = Data.fetchRequest()
        
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ofProfile.name MATCHES %@", selectedProfile.name)
request.predicate = predicate
        
do {
    let result = try context.fetch(request)
} catch {
    print("Error fetching data: \(error)")
}
```

```
! The entity Data got a ofProfile attribute which is a One - To - Many Relationship to the Profile Entity
```

> My problem is, that the `profile.name attribute` is not unique since there **can** be multiple profiles with the same name. There is **no attribute that is 100% unique**.
>
> **So here's my question: Is there a way to only fetch the data of one specific profile without having a unique attribute. Maybe use the `ObjectID` of the active profile?**

I hope you guys can think of a solution for this problem. Thanks a lot for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a `Profile` object, and wish to fetch `Data` objects related to it, you can use:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY ofProfile == %@", selectedProfile)
```

(if it's a to-many relationship), or

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ofProfile == %@", selectedProfile)
```

(if it's to-one).

But equally, if you have an inverse relationship (and you probably should), let's say called `data`, then you can use that without the need for a fetch:

```
let relatedData = selectedProfile.data
```

Comment: Of course I have a inverse relationship however I didn't think of that;) Thanks a lot. You helped me a lot. So with the third code line of you I get a Set of Data Objects without having to perform a fetch request. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

First of all do not name a custom class `Data`. There is a struct `Data` in the Foundation framework.

The error says that `ofProfile` is an `NSSet` so you cannot apply this predicate.

A possible solution is to search in the type of `ofProfile` for records which match the name **and** the *Data* relationship.

Comment: The Entity is not called Data. Don't worry, I just named it Data for Simplicity in my Question. What Do you mean with the error, I didn't get one so far. And the code works perfectly. The only problem is, that when I create a second profile with the same name, the data of both profiles gets loaded up.